# How to connect to AWS ElasticSearch using npm elasticsearch and http-aws-es?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-sdk, aws-elasticsearch

I am using the npm elasticsearch package to search my AWS ES domain. Everything seems to work fine when I use Postman to make POST requests with my AWS IAM credentials. 
I wanted to do the same in my code (node.js). I referred to this answer here: 
[How to make calls to elasticsearch apis through NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50973930/how-to-make-calls-to-elasticsearch-apis-through-nodejs)

Here is code:

```
const elasticsearch     = require('elasticsearch');
const awsHttpClient     = require('http-aws-es');
const AWS               = require('aws-sdk');

const client            = new elasticsearch.Client({ 
    host: 'my-aws-es-endpoint', 
    connectionClass: awsHttpClient,
    amazonES: {
        region: 'us-east-1',
        credentials: new AWS.Credentials('my-access-key','my-secret-key')
    }
});
```

But when I run client.search(), it fails with an error:

```
Elasticsearch ERROR: 2018-10-31T15:12:22Z
  Error: Request error, retrying
  POST https://my-endpoint.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/my-index/student/_search => Data must be a string or a buffer
```

It also gives me a warning

```
Elasticsearch WARNING: 2018-10-31T15:12:22Z
  Unable to revive connection: https://my-endpoint.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/
```

When I use just the aws-sdk, it works fine (probably because I sign the request there?)

Can someone suggest what I am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve this by specifying the region. There is a problem with the elasticsearch client where it's not able to the pick the region which we specify in

```
amazonES: {
        region: 'us-east-1',
        credentials: new AWS.Credentials('my-access-key','my-secret-key')
    }
}
```

I solved it by specifying the region using AWS.config.region before the above code

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
```